# Questions about the stability (and stationarity) of a system and state space representations

Tags: arima, stochastic-processes, stationarity, state-space-models

I'm pretty new to the topic and I'm trying to understand how to determine the stability of a process. I'm giving this discrete-time stochastic system:

$$
\cases{ s_t = 2s_{t-2} + 3w_{t-2} \\
y_t = s_t + v_t \\
w_t = wn(0, q) \\
v_t = wn(0, r) \\
w_t \perp v_t
}
$$
where $w_t = wn(0, q)$ means that the process $w_t$ is white noise with 0 mean and variance $\sigma^2 = q$ and $w_t \perp v_t$ means that the processes are uncorrelated.

**I'm asked if the process $y_t$ is stationary** and I'm finding some difficulties in deriving the answer.

I (think I)'ve written $s_t$ in terms of his transfer function (interpreting $z$ as the lag operator):

$$
s_t = \frac{3z^{-2}}{1 - 2z^{-2}} w_t
$$

This transfer function has poles in $\pm \sqrt{2}$, outside the unit circle, hence I'd say that this process is not stable and that $y_t$ cannot be stable, either.

Regarding the *stationarity* of $y_t$: do I have to solve the discrete SDE and evaluate mean and variance of $y_t$ or is a better and smarter way to answer the question?

---

I know that an ARMA model

$$
y(t) = H(z) e(t) \\
H(z) = \frac{C(z)}{A(z)} = \frac{1 + c_1z^{-1} + \dots c_n z^{-n}}{1 + a_1z^{-1} + \dots a_n z^{-n}} \\
e(t) = wn(0, \sigma_e^2)
$$

can be represented in the state space through the *canonical observability representation*

$$
\cases{
x(t+1) = A(t)x(t) + B(t)e(t) \\
y(t) = C(t)x(t) + D(t)e(t)
}
$$

but, since $s_t$ is not ARMA, can I give a state space representation of $s_t$ and (maybe) work it out in that domain?

Thank you for your help!